# Is Imap.get() expensive in Hazelcast if Hazelcast cluster is running in the Cloud?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a distributed map stored in hazelcast. My hazelcast cluster run in a cloud either private or public. My app may not run on the same network where hazelcast cluster is running. 
My app tries to access distributed map using IMap.get() may be thousands per second. I tried to major performance of the above operation on the local cluster by running hazelcast cluster on my local machine. I could read everything in 15-20ms. But I am not getting the same performance if hazelcast cluster runs in the cloud.

If you are reading a map, more frequently, Will it increase the load on hazelcast in the cloud environment?, yes any reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Performance of running software locally will always be different than running in a distributed environment, more so when servers are located elsewhere - network latencies being the most prominent factor.

Servers in cloud, app on local = not the recipe for best performance. Either move all cluster components- servers and app clients, in one network (aim for same availability zone if looking for best performance) or expect delays. Its not the cloud in particular that deteriorates the performance, its the way VMs are setup in cloud. For example, if one VM is in us-east-1 and other in London and your app is in Tokyo then expect inferior performance numbers.